# on reboot, Debian 11 always open /run/systemd folder

Tags: debian, systemd, reboot

on reboot, Debian 11 always open `/run/systemd` folder, whereas before, Debian did not open any specific folder after restart. This doesn't cause any problems, but nevertheless.

Edit: grep search

```
~$ grep -r /run/systemd $HOME/.??*
/home/lunar/.bash_history:/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
/home/lunar/.bash_history:cd /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
/home/lunar/.bash_history:/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
/home/lunar/.cache/sessions/Thunar-24a92edbf-804a-4cab-b0ec-cc7b5d660023:URI=file:///run/systemd
grep: /home/lunar/.mozilla/firefox/3allhj9p.Default-User/places.sqlite-wal: binary file matches
grep: /home/lunar/.mozilla/firefox/3allhj9p.Default-User/places.sqlite: binary file matches
```

---

```
~/.cache/sessions$ cat Thunar-24a92edbf-804a-4cab-b0ec-cc7b5d660023
[Thunar-1651872231-2573164324]
PAGE=0
URI=file:///run/systemd
```

Comment: Do you mean "open a folder" as a window in a GUI? Or just as "it appears in a `lsof` listing"? If it's the former, try creating a new user account and log in as that user after a reboot, instead of your regular user account. If the folder does not open on a new user account, the problem is within user-specific desktop settings.

Comment: It appears as window in the desktop, just show `systemd` directory content. Even though I haven't opened it before the reboot.

Comment: So, have you checked what happens if you create a new user account (just for testing, you can delete it afterwards) and log in with that instead of your normal user account?

Comment: I added a new user, rebooted: `systemd` folder does not open on a new user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you indicated this happens with your regular user account only, not on a new account created for testing. So whatever triggers opening of that folder is part of the settings of your regular user account.

Try searching for the string `/run/systemd` among the hidden "dot files and folders" of your user account, by running this command when logged in with your regular user account:

```
grep -r /run/systemd $HOME/.??*
```

The pathname of the file(s) you'll find the string `/run/systemd` in should be indicative of the file's purpose. Once you find the file(s), someone here should be able to give you advice on how to edit that file, or even if it's safe to just delete that file.

The results will probably indicate some file that stores some part of the configuration of your desktop environment. You might have at some point of time (accidentally?) saved the session state with the `/run/systemd` folder opened, and now your desktop environment will be trying to restore your desktop to that precise state each time you log in, until you tell it otherwise.

Or if your desktop environment is configured to always save the session state on logout (which at least used to be the factory default on some desktop environments, I think?), the session state file might have become read-only for some reason; if so, resetting the permissions of that file to normal and one logout with the annoying folder closed might be all that's needed to fix it.

---

OK, you found it:

```
/home/lunar/.cache/sessions/Thunar-24a92edbf-804a-4cab-b0ec-cc7b5d660023:URI=file:///run/systemd
```

The pathname indicates this is a session cache file for your Thunar file manager, and so it should be safe to delete.

You may have to logout from the GUI, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and login in text mode, then delete any session cache files while Thunar is not running:

```
rm /home/lunar/.cache/sessions/Thunar-*
```

Then logout, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to GUI mode to login again, now hopefully without the annoying folder window.

Comment: it looks the file `Thunar-24a92edbf-804a-4cab-b0ec-cc7b5d660023` contains wrong path?

Comment: Thank you! I used this command to delete the sessions cache: `rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions/*`
This helped, and stopped the `systemd` folder from popping up at computer startup.